# Bash: combine parameter indirection with arithmetic expansion?

Tags: bash

The script below prints positional parameters. The idea is to skip some optional arguments (where the number of optional args is given by `SKIP`), and then get the last two arguments. For the last arg, for example, I use an arithmetic expansion to get `V2`, and then indirect expansion of `V2` to get `A2`. Running `test a b c`, for example, prints `b` and `c`.

Question: the two-step expansion is clunky. Is there a one-liner that will derive the value of a given arg?

```
#!/bin/bash

SKIP=1

# get second-from-last arg
V1=$(( SKIP+1 ))
A1=${!V1}

# get last arg
V2=$(( SKIP+2 ))
A2=${!V2}

echo A1 is $A1
echo A2 is $A2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an array from the positional parameters, you can use array indexing to get the desired values.

```
args=( "$@" )
echo "${args[-1]}"  # Last argument
echo "${args[-2]}"  # Next to last argument

echo "${args[4]}"  # Get the 5th argument (zero-based indexing)
echo ${args[SKIP+3]}  # If SKIP=1, same as above.
```

Array indices are evaluated in an arithmetic context, the same as if you used `$((...))`.

Answer (score 1):

`$@` and bash arrays could be what you're looking for:

```bash
$ cat foo
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a args=( "$@" )
declare -i skip=1
for (( i = skip; i < ${#args[@]}; i++ )); do
    printf '%d: %s\n' "$i" "${args[i]}"
done

$./foo b c d
1: b
2: c
3: d
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#! /bin/bash -p

skip=1

a1=${@:skip+1:1}
a2=${@:skip+2:1}

declare -p a1 a2
```

To explicitly get the values of the last two positional parameters try:

```
a1=${@: -2:1}
a2=${@: -1:1}
```

- See the description of "Substring Expansion" (`${parameter:offset:Length}`) in the [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) section of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for an explanation of `${@:skip+1:1}` etc.
- The spaces are required before `-2` and `-1` in the expressions that get the last two parameters.  (`:-` does something different).
- `declare -p` shows the values of variables in unambiguous ways.  It's generally better than using `echo` (or even the generally better `printf`).
- See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375) for an explanation of why I changed the variable names to `skip`, `a1`, and `a2`.